# Combine two arrays on Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have these two nodes that I need to get on a single http call. I am trying to achieve this by using async/await to get the two nodes and then combine them using concat or forEach. But it seems that even though I am awaiting responses, inside the function they are still promises and not the data itself. This is my basic example:

```
exports.searchVisit = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date(Date.now());
  let todayVisits = await admin.database().ref('/visits/').once('value');
  let frequentVisits = await admin.database().ref('/frequent_visits/').once('value');

  console.log(todayVisits); // Prints an object (I guess it is a promise)

  res.status(200).send(todayVisits); // Returns correctly the data on visits collection
});
```

How could I achieve to return todayVisits and frequentVisits combined? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention " two collections". Are you using the Realtime Database (as suggest your code) or Firestore?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using realtime database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code, merging the two JavaScript objects obtained with `val()`, as explained by Doug, should do the trick:

```
exports.searchVisit = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const today = new Date(Date.now());
  let todayVisits = admin.database().ref('/visits/').once('value');
  let frequentVisits = admin.database().ref('/frequent_visits/').once('value');

  const [todayVisitsSnap, frequentVisitsSnap] = await Promise.all([
          todayVisits,
          frequentVisits
  ]);

  res.status(200).send({ ...todayVisitsSnap.val(), ...frequentVisitsSnap.val() }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `todayVisits` is a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) type object.  It is not a promise.  Logging that DataSnapshot object is not likely to be useful.  If you want to see the raw data inside that snapshot, call [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) on it to get a JavaScript object with the entire set of data in that snapshot.  This is also what you probably want to send to the client (not the entire contents of the DataSnapshot).